# how to replace current repeater in angular

Tags: javascript, templates, angularjs, replace, repeater

I init a repeater colorSetOne in the HTML, and then, I want to replace with another repeater colorSetTwo, how to do this (it can be trigger by an event)?  and here is jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8xWRm/

HTML:

```
<ul ng-app ng-controller="cubeCtrl">
<li ng-repeat="color in colorSetOne">{{color}}</li>
```

Javascipt:

```
function cubeCtrl($scope){
$scope.colorSetOne = ["red","blue","green","oringe"]
$scope.colorSetTwo = ["blue","red","black","white"]
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to reassign `colorSetOne`

```
$scope.colorSetOne = $scope.colorSetTwo;
```

If you want to keep `colorSetOne` then you should put your repeater on another variable like `colorSet` and just assign the appropriate color set as needed.

Comment: too much expensive, isn't it?

Comment: Maybe but he's asking how to replace the list, not append one to the other.